# What's the song sung by the dink dinks?

Tags: music-identification, spaceballs

In *Spaceballs*, the "Jawas" are walking singing their little "dink dink" jingle. I believe this is a normal tune and not one just made up for the movie. What song is it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a version of the [Colonel Bogey March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonel_Bogey_March) by Lieutenant F. J. Ricketts

---

The Official 19th Anniversary Soundtrack lists it as

> Dink March (Colonel Bogey March)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps worth noting the prominent place the tune had in *The Bridge on the River Kwai* a film that many of Brooks' original target audience would be quite familiar with. I recall seeing it run as the late night movie fairly often in the 70s

Comment: Spaceballs: The Official 19th Anniversary Soundtrack "Merchandising!  Merchandising!  Where the real money from the movie is made!"

Comment: Another wrinkle to this answer is that Sir Alec Guinness was in The Bridge on the River Kwai, where the song is from, adding another connection to Star Wars.